# Update operation concurrency on multiple nodes

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, paas

I have a single application , maintained on two different nodes on cloud. I have a scheduler in the application which triggers every 5 minutes, which perform some update operation in database. How can I avoid the two operations to cause anomaly in database. Is there a way one application may know, that other instance is already been triggered or any sort of inter node communication that may happen in cloud foundry.

Many Thanks

Comment: I would look into an architecture which uses a message oriented solution.  IMHO, you have selected an architecture/implementation which is prone to difficulties.

Comment: Or rely on data in the database: transaction (and isolation level) to prevent simultaneous updates, possibly an additional column storing a last-updated timestamp you can check for before doing an update?

Comment: The application is hosted on cloud on multiple nodes and is invoked as a rest services. SO only one of the node will respond to the external rest call. The only challenge is the scheduling mechanism which is getting performed within the application . Is there a way that two apps could know, the one has started the scheduling process, and other should not do that .. In other words intercommunication between same applications hosted on two different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options come to mind for Cloud Foundry:

1. Create a distributed "lock" with your database.  This could be as simple as a table or record in the DB that the scheduler checks out first before it does anything else.  Once it has the lock, the scheduler can work.  If it fails to obtain the lock, it goes back to sleep.  Then when it's done, it returns the lock.

   If you have lots of work to do, you could divide it into sections and have locks for each section, that way you could spread the work out across your different instances.  This gets more complicated though, so you'd have to weigh the advantages against the extra complication to see if it's worth it for your use case.
2. Only run the scheduler on the first node.  You can determine the first node by looking at your application instance number.  Either the env variable `CF_INSTANCE_INDEX` or `VCAP_APPLICATION`, which contains JSON and has an `instance_index` property.  For either option, the value will be 0 for the first instance.  If it's 0, the scheduler runs.  If it's greater than zero, the scheduler doesn't run.

Hope that helps!